# regex to find all digits groups, that are grouped as more than one, inside a text

Tags: regex, regex-negation, regex-group

I am trying to find all the numbers in a text, much numbers with dots or commas. However I want to avoid when a single digit appear in a word, for example 'hou2se', but any case with more than a digit should be valid. For now I have the following regular expression:

```
'(\d+\.?\d*)'
```

which matches what I want, I don't know how to avoid that specific pattern. 
I have tried with something like this:

```
'(\d+\.?\d*)(?![A-Za-z]\d[A-Za-z])'
```

But it doesn't work. How can I avoid finding 'hou2se', for example? 
Note: I want to aboid founding a digit surrounded by letters.

EDIT: some examples:

```
"5.5asd" = match 5.5
"asd1.3 " = match 1.3
"5,2" = match 5,2 
"asd 5,4 asd 2.2 as5d" = match 5,4 and 2.2
"asd 45. mms555as 4545 sas 5book" = match 45. 555 4545 5
```

I haven't include comma but I know that I will need to put [.,] instead of "\.".

Comment: Please provide more examples and the result. How about "5.5asd", "asd1.3 ", "5,2" or "asd 5,4 asd 2.2 as5d"?

Comment: what about asd2.2xyz?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On possibility to get your values is to match what you don't want and then to capture in a group what you do want using an [alternation](https://www.regular-expressions.info/alternation.html):

[`\b(?:[a-zA-Z_]+\d[a-zA-Z_]+)\b|(\d+(?:[.,]\d*)?)`](https://regex101.com/r/hpoadO/2)

Your values will be in capturing group 1

**That would match:**

- `\b` Word boundary
- `(?:` Non capturing group

  - `[a-zA-Z_]+\d[a-zA-Z_]+` Match a digit `\d` between one or more word characters `[a-zA-Z_]+` (without the digits)
- `)` Close non capturing group
- `\b`Word boundary
- `|` Or
- `(` Capturing group

  - `\d+(?:[.,]\d*)?` Match one or more digits followed by an optional part that matches a dot or comma and zero or more digits
- `)` Close capturing group

Comment: Nice idea! Do you even need the word boundaries? And (?<capgroup>\d+[.,]?(?:\d+)?) makes "45." valid too

Comment: @Chriz Nice catch! I have updated that last part to `\d*`

Answer (score 0):

`\b\d[^A-Za-z]+|\d[^A-Za-z]+\b` ought to do the trick. This checks for either a word break followed by a digit and a series of non-letters, or a digit and a series of non-letters followed by a word break. It will not match anything that has letters on both sides.